# Tag Merge Request: Economy and Economic History

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I think that economy is really a subset of economic history. I don't know that economy questions would lose anything by being subsumed by economic history questions.

Thoughts?

Comment: If this is History SE, wouldn't it be redundant to have a history tag?

Comment: @Luke yes, I didn't see that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge of economic history into the economy tag has been completed

Comment: GJ. Yay for moderators!

Comment: @canadiancreed It can now be marked complete

Answer (score 3):

I'd actually argue (in fact *did* argue when the tag was created) that it should be the other way around. Everything on this site should by definition be history, so tacking "history" onto a lot of tags just increases the length of our tags without adding any useful information to them.

Comment: That's what I was trying to say in my earlier comment. +1